# Is there a formula for $(a+b)^n+(a-b)^n$?

Tags: binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

Is there a formula for $(a+b)^n+(a-b)^n$? Just curious. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there is:
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}a^{n-k}b^{k}+\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^{k}\binom{n}{k}a^{n-k}b^{k} & = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}a^{n-k}b^k\left(1+(-1)^k\right) \\
& = 2\sum_{k \text{ even } \\ 0 \leq k \leq n} \binom{n}{k}a^{n-k}b^k.
\end{align*}

Comment: Woah thanks so much :)